# How to make a question about a movie and references suitable?

Tags: discussion

Update: Thanks to the moderator the question is reopened!

This was the question I asked:
[Identify the movie that the rain scene in Cable Guy mimics?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8915/cable-guy-scenes-reference-list)

It got closed, but I can't see which FAQ applies to a question that is asking how one would go about finding more stuff about a movie. After all the assumption was this is the place were the movie gurus would hang out and some of their wisdom would hopefully rub off on rest of us.

Comment: seriously dude....You need to clean up the question at first!

Comment: Thanks dude, how do I ask please give guidance to find info on a movie that a google master has failed to find?

Comment: [How to ask a smart question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question)

Comment: @Mistu4u : thanks, I'll study that and revise the question with using more gray matter.

Comment: bdw, Dont forget to follow the [faq here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting more. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial question was essentially a `list question`.  A question where multiple answers can be correct and no answer can really be wrong.  These are disallowed because they turn into blatant discussion at best, which is also disallowed.

As has been said before, this site does allow for more open-ended questions than most other SE's but we must draw the line somewhere.

Asking about a specific scene and it's meaning, however, is perfectly fine as long as the scene is justified to be talked about.  If it was asking "Why is this character defecating in a toilet" well that is going to get closed quick, due to it not having any significance in the plot, for example.

Comment: Notice: I have been sick so I hope this answer makes sense.